# Search for a number within cell range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can search for a certain number in a range of cells? For example `=SEARCH(M5,A:A)`. That returns `#VALUE!` error. Anyone has experience on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the COUNTIF function which will count a range for a specified value. You can then wrap the COUNTIF function in an IF statement to display a nicer message

```
=IF(COUNTIF(YOUR_RANGE, YOUR_CRITERIA) = 1, "Found", "Not Found")
```